# How to allot dynamic drive access permission from csv data to google drive folders?

Tags: csv, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, google-drive-shared-drive

I Have a `csv file` with `first name`, `ID number` and `email id` data of a certain set of people. I want to take this information and with it, in a Google Drive parent folder I want to create subfolders with the name `firstname_ID_number` and set the access permission of each folder to the corresponding email only.

In other words each person in the list should only be able to access their own folder in that drive and not others'.

My first thought was to use `Google Colab` and `Google Drive API` to get this done. But I do not know how or where to start with. I would appreciate some kind guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You could start by importing your csv file in Google Sheets and later use Apps Script for your task.

Therefore, assuming your sheet will end up looking something similar to this:

| First Name | ID Number | Email ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | N1 | E1 |
| Name2 | N2 | E2 |
| Name3 | N3 | E3 |

You can make use of the `Drive` advanced service in order to create the folders and assign the permissions. You can take a look at the below script in order to achieve this:

#### Code

```
function mainFunction() {
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID");
  let sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME");
  let nameCol = sheet.getRange(START_ROW, START_COL, NO_ROWS, NO_COLS).getValues();
  let idCol = sheet.getRange(START_ROW, START_COL, NO_ROWS, NO_COLS).getValues();
  let emailCol = sheet.getRange(START_ROW, START_COL, NO_ROWS, NO_COLS).getValues();

  for (let i = 0; i < nameCol.length; i++) {
    let fileName = nameCol[i + 1][0] + "_" + idCol[i + 1][0];
    let folderId = createFolder(fileName);
    createPermission(emailCol[i + 1][0], folderId);
  }
}

function createFolder(fileName) {
  let optionalArgs = { supportsAllDrives: true };
  let resource = {
    title: fileName,
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    parents: [{
      "id": "SHARED_DRIVE_ID"
    }]
  }
  let folder = Drive.Files.insert(resource, null, optionalArgs);
  return folder.id;

}

function createPermission(emailAddress, folderId) {
  let optionalArgs = { supportsAllDrives: true };
  let resource = {
    role: "ROLE",
    type: "TYPE",
    emailAddress: emailAddress
  }
  Drive.Permissions.insert(resource, folderId);
}
```

#### Explanation

The script is composed of three functions: `mainFunction`, `createFolder` and `createPermission`. The `mainFunction` is used to gather all the values from the sheet while `createFolder` and `createPermission` are used to create the folder and assign the necessary permission to it. Since you are working with shared drives, the right approach here is to use the `Drive` advanced service.

#### Reference

- [Range Class getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getValues());
- [Drive Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive);
- [Drive API v2 Files:insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert);
- [Drive API v2 Permissions:insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert).

Comment: Appreciate your answer although I solved this problem. If anyone wants a reference it can be found 
[here](https://github.com/amalp12/Google-Drive-Dynamic-Folder-Permission-Allocator) .